# Compilation of ghost functions in SPARK 2014

Tags: ada

I wish to abstract out some common patterns in pre and post conditions into a function in order to make the conditions more readable. From the documentation, it looks like ghost functions solve this issue.

I depend on the fact that overflows are eliminated in assertions (via a configuration pragma) so I don't believe that I can use ghost functions with code. The SPARK documentation contains the following example of a ghost function without code in http://docs.adacore.com/spark2014-docs/html/ug/spark_2014.html#ghost-functions :

```
function A_Nonexecutable_Ghost_Function (Lo, Hi : Natural) return Natural
with Pre        => Lo <= Hi,
     Post       => A_Nonexecutable_Ghost_Function'Result in Lo .. Hi,
     Convention => Ghost,
     Import;
-- The body of the function is not declared elsewhere.
```

However this, and any other ghost function like it that I try to write, results in:

```
warning: null global effect assumed on imported subprogram
```

And that warning stops compilation. Trying to say `Global => ()` doesn't work. Can I suppress the warning? There's no obvious `-Werror` on the gnatprove command line that I can see to remove either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper syntax is `Global => null` instead of `Global => ()`, then the warning goes away.

Comment: @manuBriot, I’d have thought that once a user has said `Import` they ought not to have to state `Globals => null`? (there’s no suggestion of this in the manual that OP links to)

Comment: @SimonWright Import and Global are orthogonal aspects. Import says that the body of this subprogram is not provided in Ada. Global describes the effects on Global variables of the subprogram. An imported subprogram can of course have effects on Global variables, even in SPARK a Ghost function may read Global state. So it makes sense to encourage the user to specify both aspects.

Comment: Refer again to the OP’s link to the manual. `Import` on a ghost function is a special convention which means it is a **non-executable** function which has no body at all; if it can’t be executed it can’t affect global or any other state. If `Global => null` is necessary for compilation to succeed, as OP states, then the manual is wrong.

Comment: @SimonWright A ghost function, even an `import`ed one, can read global state (in SPARK, a function cannot _write_ any global state). You are right that _if you run the program_, it won't read any global state, because it won't ever be called! But if the read of global state was declared, the analysis of the program will do as if this was the case. Note that to make the _warning_ go away in the OP example, a `Global` annotation is needed, but not necessarily `Global => null`. This was however what the OP wanted, so I provided it.